# How to correctly get the results from MgetResponse object?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

In our app, we are synchronizing some of the data to elasticsearch, and some of this data is users' records. The app is grails 5.1 and we are using `Elasticsearch Java API Client` for elasticsearch integration.

The indexing is working perfectly fine, and an example of user data looks like this:
[image]

Now, we have this following function that suppose to get the list of users by their ids:

```
PublicUser[] getAllByIds(Long[] ids) {
        MgetRequest request = new MgetRequest.Builder()
                .ids(ids.collect { it.toString() }.toList())
                .index("users")
                .build()
        MgetResponse<PublicUser> response = elasticSearchClientProviderService.getClient().mget(
                request,
                PublicUser.class
        )

        response.docs().collect {
            it.result().source()
        }
    }
```

And when the response holds at least one user record, we are getting a list of `PulicUser` objects -> **as expected**.

However, if the search result is empty, the eventual return from this function is a list with one `null` element.

**Some investigation**

`response.docs()` holds a single non-existing document (looks like this one is filled with the request data).
[image]

And, as a result, the return from this function is (as I mentioned above) list of one `null` element.
[image]

**Another observation:**

I expected that response object will have `.hits()`, for the actual results are accessible through: `response.hits().hits()`. But now of that exist.

The only season I started looking into `docs()` directly is because if this documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/docs-multi-get.html

There is a lack of `Elasticsearch Java API Client` docs. They mostly refer to REST API docs.

What is the correct way to get the list of results from `mget` request?

Answer (score 0):

For now, I am solving this the following way. Will be glad to see if there is a better way, though.

```
PublicUser[] getAllByIds(Long[] ids) {
        MgetRequest request = new MgetRequest.Builder()
                .ids(ids.collect { it.toString() }.toList())
                .index("users")
                .build()
        MgetResponse<PublicUser> response = elasticSearchClientProviderService.getClient().mget(
                request,
                PublicUser.class
        )


        List<PublicUser> users = []
        response.docs().each {
            if (it.result().found()) {
                users.add(it.result().source())
            }
        }

        users
    }
```